# gcc atomic built-in functions: any known conflicts within multithreading environments?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, boost

So, I want to avoid future problems when using `__sync_fetch_and_add` in a context of Boost-based multithreaded application.

Any chance that a low-level threading implementation used by Boost (pthreads here) would affect the functionality of buitins?

Comment: For newer versions of gcc, you might consider using the more recent [`__atomic`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtins are the intrinsics.

They don't make assumptions about the libraries that will be used in applications.

There is no way it can interfere.

---

(On a tangent: Some libraries, like Boost Asio, optionally can use C++11 atomics instead of `boost::detail::atomic_count` [(doc)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/atomic.html))